# Angular valueChanges updateOn: blur how to wait before all valuechanges completed before submit

Tags: angular

I have a reactive form with some fields that i have subscribed to.
The user enters a value on a subscribed control, tabs or clicks out of the field (blur event), a backend/http call will take place to get some additional info and fill some other fields.

This all works perfectly.

The problem arises when the user doesn't click out of the field but clicks directly on our save button that starts the logic before saving. 70 out of 100 times this also works ok, the backend call is fast enough to get the additional info and then starts the saving process but the other 30 times we are missing some info.

Off course i can do some manual checks and validators but i thought there must be a way to make sure all my valuechanges are not pending and make sure they are all completed.

Many thanks!

Comment: If its a required field, disable the button conditionally.

Comment: No its not required

Comment: If its not required, why you want to wait till the API response?

Comment: Because that additionall backend call gathers some important info. But is only needed when the user has entered something in the field with the listener on it. Also users can now directly click on save in the current application. If i disable the button that's not possible anymore. Then they should first tab or click out of the field, not good for ux.

Comment: so instead of blur event you can use onChange with a debounce to trigger the API call.

Comment: That was our final solution indeed.. ;) we also have another option to do a final check before submit but i would like a more general solution where i can be sure that all pending valuechanges have finished.

Answer (score 0):

You can disabled the button for the time when the API is in progress.

-Maintain a boolean variable and use the tap operator to update its
value.Internally use the `switchMap` operator to make the API calls and once its is done disable the boolean value.

```
this.firstName.valueChanges
          .pipe(
            tap((x) => (this.isLoading = true)),
            switchMap(() => {
              return of('xxxx').pipe(delay(2000));
            }),
            tap((x) => (this.isLoading = false))
          )
          .subscribe((x) => console.log(x));
```

-Use the boolean variable to disable the button

```
<button [disabled]="isLoading">Submit</button>
```

In this way your button will be enabled by default however as soon as user started typing something in the textbox button will be disabled till the API response completed.

Demo:- https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kheete?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Note:- Delay has been added to showcase the workflow.

Comment: That would only work if we set the control to update on change, right?

Comment: By default control value is updated on change. If you want to update it only in vase of blur you need to set it explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

so i think i found a sort of solution. Maybe i can expand it further so i don't have to put booleans inside all my valuechanges functions but for now this seems to be working fine.

In my triggered valuechanges function i start with a boolean set to true to mark that we have activevalue changes that are currently in progress.

example:

```
async valueChangeFunc() {
this.activeValueChanges = true;
//await..http call 
//more logic
this.activeValueChanges = false;
}
```

in my submit function i will wait untill the activevaluechanges boolean is resolved to false.

example:

```
 async submitForm() {
    await waitFor(() => !this.activeValueChanges);
    //mark formcontrols as touched etc.
    const values = this.myForm.getRawValue();
    const errors = getValidationErrors(this.myForm);
    //more logic
}
```

key in this all is the following function that waits before continuing

```
const waitFor = async (condFunc: () => boolean) => {
  return new Promise<void>((resolve) => {
    if (condFunc()) {
      resolve();
    }
    else {
      setTimeout(async () => {
        await waitFor(condFunc);
        resolve();
      }, 100);
    }
  });
};
```

Hope it may help someone, works now 100 out of 100 times

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

It's tricky to handle If listening to valuechanges is important for your user experience instead of set a button for the user to submit his changes.
You can make an out of box sloution for this senario Like:

**JSON.stringify(value):** To make the value easy to track it's changes.

**distinictUntilChanged():** Will not emit the same value twice.

**debounceTime(500):** The time need to elapsed after last emit value in this example is 500ms.

**JSON.parse(value):** Will return the value to the original state.

```
this.form.valuechanges.pipe(
  map(value => JSON.stringify(value),
  distinictUntilChanged(),
  debounceTime(500),
  map(value => JSON.parse(value)))
  .subscribe(value => {
    ...Your Code
  });
```

Comment: Not sure if i fully understand. The user is clicking a submit button but at that time the valuechanges is not finished yet. So its basically a timing issue.